# Algorithm to convert a double to a char array in Java (without using objects like Double.toString or StringBuilder)?

Tags: java, algorithm, types, numbers, primitive-types

Does anyone know where I can find that algorithm? It takes a double and StringBuilder and appends the double to the StringBuilder *without creating any objects or garbage*. Of course I am not looking for:

```
sb.append(Double.toString(myDouble));

// or

sb.append(myDouble);
```

I tried poking around the Java source code (I am sure it does it somehow) but I could not see any block of code/logic clear enough to be re-used.

Comment: Why does `sb.append(myDouble);` not do what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jesper it creates quite a few objects.

Comment: If the Java source code "does it somehow", then why does the same Java source code not already use that same technique in `StringBuilder.append(double)`? Seems rather wasteful not to use this optimal technique if you have it. That leads me to suspect that either they don't have that code, or it *isn't* optimal, at least in the opinion of your JVM implementer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written this for ByteBuffer. You should be able to adapt it. Writing it to a direct ByteBuffer saves you having to convert it to bytes or copy it into "native" space.

See [`public ByteStringAppender append(double d)`](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/chronicle/impl/AbstractExcerpt.java)

If you are logging this to a file, you might use the whole library as it can write around 20 million doubles per second sustained. It can do this without system calls as it writes to a memory mapped file.

Comment: Btw: the strings it produces can be shorter than the builtin ones. (by a digit) This is because it checks to see if the value it has written has the same representation as the double whereas the builtin in one cautiously adds an extra digit sometimes.